# Multidimensional Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have currently something like this:

```
var selectAThing = {
        "ID" : "ProductName" ,
        "5" : "abc" ,
        "29" : "efg" ,
        "28" : "HIJ" ,
        "11" : "xyz"
        "23" : "efg" ,
        "15" : "HIJ" ,
        "40" : "xyz"
    };

$.each(selectAThing, function(key, value) {   
     $('.mySelect')
          .append($('<option>', { value : key })
          .text(value)); 
});
```

now it is showing something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="5">abc</option>
    <option value="11">abc</option>
    <option value="15">abc</option>
    <option value="23">abc</option>
    <option value="28">abc</option>
    <option value="29">abc</option>
    <option value="40">abc</option>
</select>
```

This is a list of something which will be used multiple time in a form.
So, created a js array and load it on every select list it require.

Now i added importance level on each row. if level is 1 they will show first on the select list.

```
var selectAThing = {
        level : [ "id" : "thingname", "id" : "thingname"]
    };

var selectAThing = {
        1 : [ "5" : "abc", "29" : "efg"],
        2 : [ "28" : "HIJ" , "11" : "xyz"],
        3 : [ "23" : "efg" , "15" : "HIJ" , "40" : "xyz"]
    };
```

with importance level, i want to show most importannt content on the top on the select list, order by first level, next id.
something like this:

```
<select>
    <!-- importance level 1 -->
    <option value="5">abc</option>
    <option value="29">abc</option>
    <!-- importance level 2 -->
    <option value="28">abc</option>
    <option value="11">abc</option>
    <!-- importance level 3 -->
    <option value="23">abc</option>
    <option value="15">abc</option>
    <option value="40">abc</option>
</select>
```

Now i am not sure how i am  going to convert the array to select list or even the array is right!
:(
any help!
advance thanks!

Comment: Please eloborate a bit more. So you want to just create a select-list with your "new" multidimensional array? Do you want to group these select-fields into one group per importance level?

Comment: @androidavid i changed some details on the description. sorting of the list will first level then id number. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structures do not make much sense and you should reconsider their layout.

Think about something that resembles a database table:

```
var selectAThing = [
    {id: "5", name: "abc"},
    {id: "29", name: "efg"},
    {id: "28", name: "HIJ"},
    {id: "11", name: "xyz"},
    {id: "23", name: "efg"},
    {id: "15", name: "HIJ"},
    {id: "40", name: "xyz"}
];

selectAThing.sort(function (a, b) {
    return sortAlpha(a.name, b.name);
});

$.each(selectAThing, function(i, thing) {
    $('<option>', { value: thing.id, text: thing.name }).appendTo('.mySelect');
});
```

extending that with priorities or any other attribute becomes trivial:

```
var selectAThing = [
    {id: "15", name: "HIJ", priority: 3},
    {id: "23", name: "efg", priority: 3},
    {id: "40", name: "xyz", priority: 3},
    {id: "28", name: "HIJ", priority: 2},
    {id: "11", name: "xyz", priority: 2},
    {id:  "5", name: "abc", priority: 1},
    {id: "29", name: "efg", priority: 1}
];

selectAThing.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.priority === b.priority) {
        return sortAlpha(a.name, b.name);
    } else {
        return sortNum(a.priority, b.priority);
    }
});

$.each(selectAThing, function(i, thing) {
    $('<option>', {value: thing.id, text: thing.name}).appendTo('.mySelect');
});
```

Helpers:

```
function sortAlpha(a, b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
}
function sortNum(a, b) {
    a = parseFloat(a);
    b = parseFloat(b);
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How long is that list going to be? Is it static or will it change over time? If its static just sort it once by importance and be done with it. If it is not static but not too long you could just sort it every time you need it and if it is not static but quite long you would have to keep it sorted the whole time (insert into sorted array).
Here some pseudocode:

```
var selectAThing = [
  {level:1, 5:"abc", 29:"efg"},
  {level:2, 28:"HIJ", 11:"xyz"},
  ...
];

// sort on level (ascending)
selectAThing.sort(function(a,b) {
   return a.level - b.level;
});
```

If you want to do it with a dictionary ({}), they you would have to do it like this:

```
var selectAThing = {
  1: [{"5" : "abc"}, {"29" : "efg"}],
  2: [...]
};
```

Comment: If you're changing the structure anyway, then this is probably not the way how to do it in a good way. I would rather recommend `{level: 1, entries: [...]}` instead of that fuzyy definition.

Comment: @JohnDoe90 list is not certainly static. but i will collect data from mysql where admin can change/add/edit/delete content of the list though change will be rare. on the list there will be more than 30 options and list will be used more than 10 times.